# get IE8 transition effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

fellows how can I get this color transition effect for ie8 ?
I have this [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jojaba/BEndP/1/) that works perfect in modern browsers but on IE8 it's not working!

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 transitions are not yet supported in CSS PIE. See what is supported [here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/)

Comment: yes I know, but I hope find a jQuery script or other way to do that for IE8.

Comment: There's the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) which might do what you want for on hover - otherwise treat transitions as progressive enhancement for only the browsers that support them.